# How to use feather-icons with Angular standalone components

Tags: angular, angular17, feathericons

I tried to follow the angular-feather guide:

```
const icons = {
  Camera,
  Heart,
  Github,
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CommonModule, FeatherModule.pick(icons)],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
```

But this error: `Type 'ModuleWithProviders<FeatherModule>' is not assignable to type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'.ts(2322) Component imports contains a ModuleWithProviders value, likely the result of a 'Module.forRoot()'-style call. These calls are not used to configure components and are not valid in standalone component imports - consider importing them in the application bootstrap instead.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Angular standalone component guide](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components), you can solve the problem in the same way as they solve it for the router:

> The standalone bootstrap operation is based on explicitly configuring
> a list of Providers for dependency injection. However, existing
> libraries may rely on NgModules for configuring DI. For example,
> Angular’s router uses the RouterModule.forRoot() helper to set up
> routing in an application.

Add `importProvidersFrom(FeatherModule.pick(icons))` to the list of providers in the `app.congig.ts` file (used in the `main.ts` file);

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(FeatherModule.pick(icons)),
  ],
};
```

And then add to your component imports `FeatherModule`.